# cancel all ajax request when search field is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Cancel all Ajax Request if search field is empty and if the search character length is < 3

```
$('#search-box').keyup(function() { // bind the search data

    var input = $('.search-input').val();

    if (input.length >= 3) {
        $.getJSON({ // get JSON data
            url: 'example.com?keyword=' + input,

            success: function(data) {


                    // do processing.
                    var output = "<ul class='search-lists'>"; //output search data list

                    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                        output += '<li><a>' + val.term + '</a></li>';
                    });

                    output += '</ul>';
                    $('.search-results').html(output);




            }
        }); // JSON request
    }



}); // data bind
```

Comment: search-box and .search-input both are different elements?

Comment: yes they are , here is the HTML  would appreciate your help  @dhara                                                      <section id="search-box">
            <form class="search-field">
                <input id="search" class="search-input" type="text"  value="Hello, I'm looking for..." onFocus="this.value='';" />
            </form>
            <div class="search-results"></div>
        </section>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code it's OK to use but what happens when second request finish after first request? for example first send "ab" and send "abc" later, the second result will be replace with the first. You can use abort() to abort the first connection before start the second one.

```
if(ajaxRequest){ajaxRequest.abort();}

ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
    url: '...',
    success: function(){
        /* ... */
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback can you check this url for me , once i abort the search i need my dropdown box to close how can i fix that  https://jsfiddle.net/vqvnb2p8/2/

Answer (score 0):

Use keyup event of search inputbox instead of section element.

```
$('#search').keyup(function() { // bind the search data
    var input = $('.search-input').val();
    if (input.length >= 3) {
        $.getJSON({ // get JSON data
            url: 'example.com?keyword=' + input,
            success: function(data) {
                // do processing.
                    var output = "<ul class='search-lists'>"; //output search data list

                    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                        output += '<li><a>' + val.term + '</a></li>';
                    });

                    output += '</ul>';
                    $('.search-results').html(output);
            }
        }); // JSON request
    }
}); // data bind
```